# Excel macro freezing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that merges one old and one new sheet (i.e. updating the old sheet). The macro checks if there values have changed and if there are changes, the new values from the new macro get filled into the old one.

It worked fine for several times until there was I tried to update the old sheet with a new sheet containing 1000 additional entries/rows (about 4000 entries). When the macro starts running, the progress bar on the bottom of Excel starts displaying flickering text ("Calculating 8 Threads").

What might be the reason for this issue?

```
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Orignial_excel)
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(New_excel)


' get number of Rows in both the excels

Dim Ori_row_count
Dim New_row_count
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim BB
Dim FF
Dim Ori_row_count_Up
Dim New_row_count_UP
Set sh = wb1.Sheets("Detail")
Set sh1 = wb2.Sheets("FC Detail")
Ori_row_count = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
New_row_count = sh1.Range("A1", sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


' Find out actual row count .
' Original Excel

For BB = 2 To Ori_row_count + 1
    If sh.Cells.Item(BB, 6) = Empty Then
       Ori_row_count_Up = BB
       Exit For
    End If 
Next BB

Ori_row_count = Ori_row_count_Up
Ori_row_count = 743

For FF = 4 To New_row_count
    If sh1.Cells.Item(FF, 6) = Empty Then
        New_row_count_UP = FF
        Exit For
    End If
Next FF

New_row_count = New_row_count_UP
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code manually to isolate the issue? Also, can you post The relevant parts of the code where it has the problem.

Comment: I've added the section I think must be responsible for the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this does not always find the **last used row** but if there is no data in row 1 and 2 it will find the **very last row** `1048576`

```
Ori_row_count = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
New_row_count = sh1.Range("A1", sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

therefore your loops will iterate `1048576` times and because of 2 loops it will do that 2 times.

Use this to find the last used row:

```
Dim LastUsedRow As Long
LastUsedRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

It looks like you use the loop just to find the first empty cell `sh.Cells.Item(BB, 6) = Empty` in column F. I think you could to that with just replacing the loop

```
For BB = 2 To Ori_row_count + 1
    If sh.Cells.Item(BB, 6) = Empty Then
       Ori_row_count_Up = BB
       Exit For
    End If 
Next BB
```

With just

```
Dim NextEpmtyRowF As Long
NextEpmtyRowF = sh.Cells(2, "F").End(xlDown).Row + 1

If sh.Cells(2, "F").Value = vbNullString Then
    NextEpmtyRowF = 2
ElseIf sh.Cells(3, "F").Value = vbNullString Or NextEpmtyRowF >= sh.Rows.Count Then
    NextEpmtyRowF = 3
End If
```

If you want the next epmty row after **all data** in column F you can even use the following instead of the loop:

```
Dim NextEpmtyRowF As Long
NextEpmtyRowF = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```